# how to run code for certain criteria only in a jquery multi-criteria if-statement?

Tags: javascript, jquery, if-statement, criteria

Is there a way in jquery to do the following:

```
if (  (a && b) || c ) {
   // run code only in case of c

   // run code in case of a&b or c
   }
```

or do I have to put this into separate if-clauses?

Thanks for inputs!

Comment: I see [this meme](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/19492/164403) is still alive and kicking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure what this has to do with jQuery, but yes, you'd need to use something like an `if()` to determine which one caused the initial `if()` to succeed.

```
if (  (a && b) || c ) {
  if( c )
     // do something
  else
     // do something else
}
```

Or if there's code that should always run if it passes the first test, then...

```
if (  (a && b) || c ) {
  // do a&&b || c code

  if( c )
     // do c code
}
```